# XSL replace P tags

Tags: php, xml, xslt, replace

I have a variable in XML which I would like to format. In variable, it's HTML with tags. Our system produces too many p tags, so I would like to remove all `<p>` and closing `</p>`. There is text in between p tags, which I want to stay, just remove p and /p tags.

```
 <xsl:value-of select="php:functionString('str_replace',$remove,'',normalize-space(php:functionString('html_entity_decode',description)))" />
```

I've tried with this, but this just removes one p and not closing one.

What is the best solution?

Here is the whole template. How i can implement it:
thank you for your answer. I completely new to XSL and i didn't managed to get it to work. Here is my the section of the code. I would like to remove p tag from variable description.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl" exclude-result-prefixes="php">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<products>
<xsl:for-each select="objects/object">
<xsl:element name="name"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="url"><xsl:value-of select="product_url"/></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="description"><xsl:value-of select="description"/>           </xsl:element>
</products>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is `description` a text node with an double escaped HTML fragment? In any way, why don't you register a single user defined function and use that to do the work?

Comment: Please provide an example of the input and the expected output - see: [mcve]

Comment: Input
    <p>a lot of text.</p>
    <p>a lot of text.2</p>

expected:
    a lot of text.
    a lot of text.2

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with following solution:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

So you will match `p`-tags and will only process their child nodes, like e.g. text and tags.

Answer (score 0):

**Override the** *identity rule* **in this way**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```